# Linux/C++ Copying a string to the clipboard

Tags: c++, clipboard

How would one copy a string to the clipboard?
I'd like to avoid QT and sadly i'm only finding snippets for Windows.

Comment: What system are you asking about? Or more precisely, what desktop environment?

Comment: i'm on arch/cinnemon but i'd like to keep it open

Comment: The point is that you can't keep it open. Clipboards work differently on different systems, and (as far as I know) there's no standard way to interact with them.

Answer (score 3):

You could always interact directly with xlib, but that way [<del>lies madness</del>](http://lists.slug.org.au/archives/slug-chat/2001/July/msg00054.html)<sup>[[see archived]](https://web.archive.org/web/20020713093307/https://lists.slug.org.au/archives/slug-chat/2001/July/msg00054.html)</sup> (language warning).

If you're building a GUI app, your best bet is to use whatever interface your GUI toolkit provides (such as [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html) for QT).  If you're building a command line app, just shell out to something like [xsel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/).

If you really want to proceed using only xlib, then you have to remember one thing: X does not own the clipboard; clients own the clipboard.  Your basic workflow will be to call `XSetSelectionOwner` and then sit around and handle `XSelectionRequestEvent`s until some other client takes ownership away from you.
If you're looking for an example, the xsel source is fairly easy to follow.  After that the [ICCCM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) is the place to look.

Comment: No GUI, small screenshot tool. I have everything working from grabbing a image (with xlib ^^) to uploading it and getting the url as a string. Now i just need to copy the string to my clipboard